# Що означає слово "полова"?

Tags: значення-слів

Існує народне прислів’я «Рідна мова – не полова: її за вітром  не розвієш»
Знайшла пояснення слова ПОЛОВА — жен., зап. южн. Полотица вологод. пелева, мякина, але розгубилась, що таке макина?

Comment: Що таке «зап. южн.»? Ви у словнику русського язика шукали слово з української мови?

Comment: @Sasha, Re: *«справді бракує»* — *"[Now, "but the hapless questioner could use that info!"](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/222/) In nearly all cases someone posts the same information in a (much more comprehensive) answer. Or take the time yourself to write a real answer. […] If you don't care enough to write a real answer don't, **the likelihood that you're the only person in the world** /on the site that knows that bit of info **is very small**."*

Comment: @AnastasiyaBelo4ka, Ви дивилися тлумачення слова «полова» в словнику **російської мови**; відповідно Ви знайшли тлумачення, що українське (і південноросійське, адже південноросійські діалекти часто мають дещо спільне з укр. мовою) «полова» — це те, що російською називають «мякина». Раджу натомість подивитися тлумачення слова «полова» в **українських** словниках (наприклад, [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua)) та енциклопедіях (наприклад, [Вікіпедії](//uk.wikipedia.org)).

Answer (score 3):

[СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/polova), що пан [Sasha](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/4/sasha) у коментарях пропонує до перегляду подає так:

> **ПОЛО́ВА**, и, жін.
>
> 1. *Відходи* при обмолочуванні й очищуванні зерна *хлібних злаків, льону та деяких інших культур, що використовується переважно як корм для тварин*.
> 2. перен. Що-небудь невагоме, несерйозне, таке, що не має цінності, суттєвого значення.

У цьому випадку найбільше личить перше значення, оскільки йдеться про розвіювання за вітром деяких відходів. Проте і друге теж значення не слід відкидати, адже у метафоричному значенні можна сказати, що рідна мова - це "щось", що несе у собі цінність і займає важливе значення у житті кожної людини.

Ідентичне визначення подає й [Український тлумачний словник](https://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/131988/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0), посилаючись на Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови. - "Перун". 2005.

У [словнику-довіднику Жайворонка В. В. Знаки української етнокультури](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/zhaivoronok_znaky_ukrainskoi_etnokultury/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) знаходимо доволі хороше пояснення, яке, до речі, можна як аналогію прикріпити до наведеного Вами прислів’я (адже науковець ще й пояснює використання слова "полова" саме у художній творчості):

> **поло́ва** — лушпини з обмолоче­ного зерна; ***символізує річ, що не має вартості***; тому кажуть про сло­во, яким не слід розкидатися як половою: «Слово не полова»; на­томість: «Обмова — полова, вітер її рознесе, але й очі засипле» або: «Хто з половою змішається, того свиня з’їсть».